# Django wizard: Form instantiated and clean called multiple times

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form wizard with 3 forms. The first form has only one field and uses that field to do a lookup in an external API to validate the data.

I noticed that the requests were taking unusually long, so I just added a print statement to 
the form's **init** method and to the external API client call.

It seems that my first form is being initialized and cleaned exactly 28 times every time I execute that step in the form wizard.

My first form looks like this:

## forms.py

```
class MyForm1(forms.Form):

    issue_id = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "init form 1"
        super(MyForm1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm1, self).clean()
        print "clean issue id"
        issue_id = cleaned_data.get("issue_id")

        if issue_id is not None:
            try:
                issue = ApiCLient.get_issue(issue_id)
            except APIError:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Issue not found. Try again!")
            else:
                return cleaned_data

        raise forms.ValidationError("Issue not found. Try again!")
```

The wizard stuff is pretty standard from the Django Docs, but here it goes:

## views.py

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        # some logic at the end of the wizard
```

## urls.py

```
wizard_forms = [MyForm1, MyForm2, MyForm3]
...
url(r'wizard/$', login_required(views.MyWizard.as_view(wizard_forms))),
```

As I said before, executing the first step results in

```
init form 1
clean issue id
```

Being printed to console exactly 28 times.

Any ideas? Is this a feature or a bug in the Django Form Wizard?

Comment: Is it with django dev server as well? I don't see such issue, the `clean()` for first form is called only twice - once when that form is submitted and once when `done()` is called. Is there any other details missing?

Comment: I've been going through the code and I don't see anything relevant. This is pretty straight forward. I'm setting up a clean django project to test this better right now.

Comment: I have set up a clean project with a wizard and one form and it behaves as you describe, __init__ and clean are called only twice.

Comment: I am using Django debug toolbar in my project and when I turn off TemplateDebugPanel the calls to the initial step are reduced to 5 and the calls to the form when processing the first step are reduced to 8

Comment: I too have debug toolbar but see the `clean()` called only twice.

Comment: Yes, I haven't been able to replicate this in a clean project. Have to do some more diggin' :)